# Invoke --data-checksums using pg_createcluster on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

How do you pass the *initdb* argument for data checksums to *pg_createcluster* when creating the initial cluster?

Passing the argument as per *initdb* fails for me:

```bash
pg_createcluster --data-checksums --datadir=foo/cluster_name 9.5 cluster_name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After further investigation, to specify the default initdb arguments used in pg_createcluster, the below was added in */etc/postgresql-common/createcluster.conf*:

```
initdb_options = '--data-checksums'
```

Then *pg_createcluster* was run as normal and *show data_checksums* displays:

```
data_checksums 
----------------
on
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

According the pg_createcluster usage message, initdb arguments have to go after a double dash.

```
pg_createcluster --datadir=foo/cluster_name 9.3 cluster_name -- --data-checksums
```

Comment: Using this syntax gives: "Warning: cluster names containing dashes (-) will cause problems when running from systemd. Continuing anyway", creating the cluster, without the data-checksums parameter set

Comment: JFI @user2277435: "pg_createcluster 10 my_cluster -- --data-checksums" works as expected